# Apache mod_proxy_html Substitute: how to re-use part of regex match? (regex variables?)

Tags: mod-proxy, apache-2.2, regex, regular-expressions

Have a unique URL-rewriting situation in Apache.

I need to be able to take a URL that starts with

```
"\u002f[X]"
```

or

```
'\u002f[X]"
```

Where X is the rest of some URL,
and substitute the text

```
"\u002fmeis2\u002f[X]
```

I'm not sure how the Regex works in Apache -- I think it's the same as Perl 5? -- but even then I'm a little unsure how this would be done. My hunch is that it has to do with Regex grouping and then using $1 to pull the variable out, but I'm entirely unfamiliar with this process in Apache.

Hoping someone can help -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the proxy part has to do with this but you can do this with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /meis2/$1
```

I'm assuming here that by "\u002f" you mean "/" and you mean the brackets "[]" to be part of the substitution and not in the actual URL.

EDIT

Ok, since you mean you want to rewrite the HTML output with [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/config.html). Then I think it would be something like this.

```
ProxyHTMLURLMap ^\\u002f(.*) \u002fmeis2\u002f$1 R
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for the response! To my knowledge, mod_rewrite only works on URLs where the browser is going -- not displayed URLs in pages, stylesheets, javascripts, etc. So mod_rewrite would be used largely for redirection. we're using mod_proxy_html because Apache is being implemented as a reverse proxy.

Comment: Also, to confirm, the [X] is my placeholder to mean "some character after that string" and no, that slash really is in that format. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh do you mean rewriting the html output?

Comment: that's correct. We need to rewrite that string wherever it occurs. We're basically doing a workaround for the way SharePoint 2007 handles URLs.